# Next js - Call a function on server side each time a route is changed

Tags: php, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am moving an old stack to next js and i need some help.

I have a php backend and I want to check a controller from this backend each time a route is changed, and I want to do it on server side.

For changing route, I use `Link` of `next-routes`, which have an effect only on the client side.

Is there any way I can call the controller on server-side without refreshing the app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Router's events](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents) and [Custom `App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) watching for a route change and perform the actions you need. Below you can find two sample implementations, one using class component and one using hooks. Both should do the trick.

```
// class component
import NextApp from 'next/app';
import Router from 'next/router';

class App extends NextApp {
  componentDidMount() { 
    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
      // call to your backend
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
// using hooks
import Router from 'next/router';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const doMagic = () => {
      // do your thing
    }

    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', doMagic); // add listener

    return () => {
      Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', doMagic); // remove listener
    } 
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! +1

Comment: If that solved your issue, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. In that way, you help others with similar issues to find their way :)